# Javascript 'this' Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why are 'me' and 'this' undefined when setTimeout calls it's anonymous callback?

```
    var gMyObj = new MyObj();
    gMyObj.myFunc();

    function MyObj() {
        this.myFunc = function () {
            var me = this;
            alert(me.constructor);  // defined
            setTimeout(function(me) {  
                      alert(me.constructor); // undefined
                  }, 100);
        };
    }
```

Resolution:  The selected answer is correct, thank you. My question was a simplification of the real problem I was having, which turned out to be the way jQuery modifies 'this' inside the click() method so that it points to the relevant DOM element.  I had created a new var, 'me', to hold onto 'this', and was trying to pass it in to the click method.  All I needed to do was just use 'me' inside the click event, and let the closure keep a reference to it.  Passing 'me' into click() failed, for the same reason that it failed in this example, namely, click() was not expecting it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of this:

```
function(me) {
```

Make it:

```
function() {
```

And you're good to go.

As to the 'why?' part, you are defining an anonymous function that takes an argument called `me`.  When `setTimeout()` calls that function, it passes no arguments, meaning `me` will be undefined.  Removing `me` from the argument list allows the previously defined `me` to be visible within the function.